# From which existing branch, the new branch should be created?

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

I have completed the work in `release20140116` branch and pushed it to remote.This branch is not yet merged with `master` branch. My `master` branch has updates till my last release  branch  `release20140109` . 
Now, I need to work on another module for which I would like to create another branch for next release `release20140123`.

From which existing branch should I create this new `release20140123` branch ?
`master` or `release20140116` ?

The sentence "From which existing branch",  I meant :

```
git checkout master
git branch release20140123
```

**OR**

```
git checkout release20140116
git branch release20140123
```

Comment: Uhm, that completely depends on your workflow, and if that new branch depends on the work you did in that other branch or not.

Comment: I usually create a new branch out of master. Once work is done in new branch, merge it with master. Wanted to know if there is any other best practices in the situation I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a `develop` branch, my answer would be *from `develop`*. If you don't know [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) yet, I strongly recommend you have a look at it: I find its branching model very effective. Have a look at this [brief article](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/) for a short introduction.

Anyway, in your current situation, I would personally base it on `master` as it's supposed to hold the most recent *and* stable state of the project.